# Table localization - One column for a table

Tags: mysql, sql, localization, database-normalization

I have got only one column for a table when i create two localized tables. Code as bellow.

```
-- Month
CREATE TABLE `month` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
);

-- Month Localized
CREATE TABLE `month_loc` (
  `month_id'    INT NOT NULL,
  `name`        VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(500)    NOT NULL,
  `lang_id`     INT NOT NULL
);
```

`month_loc.month_id` is the foreign key.

`month` table holds only the primary key. Other all fields should be localized. Is this table structure correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by correct? The structure seems OK but what is your specific question or concern?

Comment: @Paul I need to know what kind of issue will  have when a table has only one column.

Comment: I can't think of any particular issues having with a table with a single column would introduce.

Comment: I see no need for the `month` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If correct implies a certain degree of normalization, and the content of your columns `name` and `description` vary per `month_id, lang_id` (which would be the combined primary key of `month_loc`), then yes, your design has reached the 3rd grade of normlization.

Comment: Thanks. There is a another answer for this. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127597/get-one-column-table-when-doing-localization/127600#127600

Comment: Ah, and it is a good one. 
Unless you might need to add any data, that maps to the month, and not the language, you can of course skip creating it...
Creating it, is more of a 'normalization theory' approach, than a real use case.